# Android SDK (Eclipse) : How to create a simple timer for a simple App?

Tags: android, eclipse, time, sdk, timer

i have a simple Application about writing the sentence which is shown when the application starts.The only Problem is, i need  the application to calculate the time it took the user to write the sentence .. like when you touch "Submit" Button , the Toast message will say " Thats Right ! , It took you 3.2 Second"  As Example .

I heard you can set a timer to start on when specific action occurs ... and  you can order it to stop .

**So let's say The Timer will start when you start the app and it will stop when you touch "Submit" button , and give a toast message like above calculating the exact time it took you to write the sentience after starting the App ! ***

**Here is the App Code hope it helps : ***

```
Button w;

TextView t;

EditText e;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



w = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Write);

t= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.FTS);

e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Text);


w.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override

 public void onClick(View v) {


 String check1 = t.getText().toString();
 String check2 = e.getText().toString();

 if (check1.equals(check2))

     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Wrote it Right !!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 else if (check2.equals(""))

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"It's Empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 else 
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You wrote it wrong,try again !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

**I'm Totally new to Android so I really don't know how to do it , Thanks for your Time .***

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use the `Timer` class to start a timer session. Follow the steps:

1- define a global variable of the `Timer` and a variable to count the time like:

```
private Timer t;
private int TimeCounter = 0;
```

2- then when the activity starts, so in `onCreate` add the following: **P.S: what I did is I have a textView to show the timing while he is writing the sentence. so if you dont want that you can delete the `tvTimer` part in the following code**

```
t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tvTimer.setText(String.valueOf(TimeCounter)); // you can set it to a textView to show it to the user to see the time passing while he is writing.
                    TimeCounter++;
                }
            });

        }
    }, 1000, 1000); // 1000 means start from 1 sec, and the second 1000 is do the loop each 1 sec.
```

then when the button is clicked, stop the timing and show the `timeCounter` varaible in the `Toast`.

```
t.cancel();//stopping the timer when ready to stop.
Toast.makeText(this, "The time taken is "+ String.valueOf(TimeCounter), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**P.S: You have to deal with converting the seconds into minutes because the number could extends to 360 secs so you need to convert it to 6 minutes. you can do it in the `t.schedualeAtFixedRate` or after you done you can convert it and show it in the toast**

hope you found this useful. please give me a feedback if it worked for you.

Comment: glad I was able to help you

Answer (score 6):

Let me direct your attention to the [Chronometer Widget on the Dev Page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html)

Also here's a flavor of what you will get by using the Chronometer Widget (skip to 8:30)

[Video of Chronometer Widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ptho2yYZqTc)

**XML**

```
  <Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chronometer1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Java**

```
((Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1)).start();
((Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1)).stop();
```

Comment: This is brilliant. I kept bumping into people suggesting a custom Handler or a Timer. I was convinced there must be a default way to show time. Thanks!